# Where is the temporary object stored?

Tags: c++, object, temporary

I was wondering where a temporary object is stored when calling a function that takes a const reference.

In the scenario below, in the **foo** function we create a temporary **std::string** object and pass it as an argument to **print_name** function.
Which takes a const reference. Is it stored somewhere on a heap and than gets destroyed as soon as **print_name** function goes out of scope?

Thanks

```
void print_name(const std::string& name)
{
      std::cout << name << std::endl;
}

void foo()
{
    print_name( std::string("John") );
}
```

Comment: Didn't catch that they're constructing a `std::string` within the call, you are correct. At first glance I thought they just called the function with a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stored on the stack, not the heap. Note however that `std::string` probably makes use of the heap.

Comment: `s/it's/it migh be/`; the storage of temporary objects isn't specified by the standard.

Comment: @OP, please don't accept this answer, it's **wrong.**

Comment: It is in general correct.

Comment: no, in the general case, it's **incorrect.** It's correct in *some* special cases.

Comment: That's untrue. It is true that the standard doesn't specify the location. It is also true that the logical location for them, and the one used all compilers I've seen,is the stack.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant *"It's correct in* some *special cases"* -- `s/some/most/` or perhaps `s/some/the most common/`.